# Liferay Portlet with ICEFaces: PortletContainerLiferayImpl:170 null

Tags: jsf, null, liferay, portlet, icefaces

i have a problem. I built a liferay portlet with icefaces. when i click on the  command button i get this error:

```
09:29:49,472 ERROR [PortletContainerLiferayImpl:170] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

in particular, within the page index.xhtml there is a command button:

```
<ice:commandButton value="go" action="#{beanTest.goTo}" />
```

if you click it you should go to second.xhtml, through the navigation rules

```
<navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>go</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/second.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

The problem is that if you click, you go in a blank page (maybe second.xhtml) and you get the error above.

i hope someone may help me! thanks

Answer (score 1):

i have solved. 
I had a compatibility problem, indeed i use a liferay 6.2 and jsf2.1 but i have used the faces-bridge 3.1.x instead that the faces-bridge 3.2.x.